# How to include/import a JSP page inside a Facelets page?

Tags: jsp, jsf, include, facelets

Does somebody know if it is possible to include/import a JSP page inside a Facelets page?

After several unsuccessful tries with `<c:import>`, `<jsp:include>`, `<ui:include>` and some research on internet I think it’s time to ask it in stackoverflow.

`someJSFpage.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <f:view contentType="text/html">

        <h:head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15" />
            <title>Home</title>
        </h:head>

        <h:body>

            <xxxxx:import page="someJSPpage.jsp" />

        </h:body>

    </f:view>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) project has a component `<o:resourceInclude>` for this.

> The  component can be used to catch the output from
>   a JSP or Servlet resource and render it as output to the JSF writer.
>   In effect, this allows you to include both Servlets and JSP pages in
>   e.g. Facelets.

You can use it as follows:

```
<o:resourceInclude path="/someJSPpage.jsp" />
```

See the showcase with example [here](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/resourceInclude).

Comment: I finally found a solution exposed in this article, http://jdevelopment.nl/facelets-legacy-jsp/, which functionality Omnifaces covers. (I think both are the same).
Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! Indeed, it seems to be the same solution, probably the origin of the idea for the OmniFaces component. :)

Comment: Holy **** this will help so much.