# Include jsp file in Facelets file (Liferay portlet jsf 2.0)

Tags: jsp, liferay, facelets

I want to include jsp page into Facelets file. Then i follow this 
[How to include/import a JSP page inside a Facelets page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835594/how-to-include-import-a-jsp-page-inside-a-facelets-page)

I use this :

xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">

o:resourceInclude path="/foo.jsp"

But when i run the web app, the jsp page doesnt appear.
Any idea for help?

Comment: In order to use `xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"`, you have to install [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org). But this is not designed for portlet environments, only for servlet environments. You need to create your own taghandler.

Comment: I follow this artical http://jdevelopment.nl/facelets-legacy-jsp/ already, but the result is same?

Comment: That article of my fellow is targeted on a servlet environment, not on a portlet environment. It's actually the predecesor of `<o:resourceInclude>` (which is created by the very same blog author).

Comment: Thank you, can you tell me more details about taghandler? i dont know where can i start?